# How to clear images from JS canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been stuck trying to clear images from a canvas. I tried: `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);` as everyone suggests but that removes everything except the images. I draw images with:

```
drawImage(fl, xPos, yPos, width, height){
        image = new Image();
        image.src = fl;

        xPos = xPos + this.offset[0]; 
        yPos = yPos + this.offset[1]; 

        image.onload = function(){ 
            ctx.drawImage(this, xPos, yPos, width, height);
        }
    }
```

If it helps, I am trying to create a board game and remove a piece from the initial position when I move it to the new position. Currently, the piece is moved to the new position and the image is still appearing in the old pos. Even when I call clearcanvas and don't redraw all the pieces appear on a white background.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-clear-canvas/ try this

Comment: Can you show where clearRect is being called?

Comment: I have a draw class where I have methods for drawing things onto the canvas including the images. That's where the method with clearrect is. I then call it in another class with a "refresh()" method. ```refresh(){
        this.draw.clearCanvas();
        this.drawBoard();
        this.drawAllPieces();
    }```